# Why is $y = - 1/\lambda $ in $2\lambda x+2\lambda y+1=0$?

Tags: calculus, differential

In a textbook they give $2\lambda x+2\lambda y+1=0$ $y=-1/\lambda $

$2\lambda x+6\lambda y+5=0$ $x=1/2\lambda $

It might be very easy but I don't understand that.

Comment: What is $x$? Please give more context on what these equations represent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not write the equations in the correct order:
From:
$$2\lambda x+2\lambda y+1=0\\2\lambda x+6\lambda y+5=0$$ 
You subtract the first equation from the second and you get 
$$4\lambda y+4=0$$
Which is $$y=-\frac 1\lambda$$
Now plug this value in the first equation and you get $$2\lambda x-2+1=0$$
or $$x=\frac1{2\lambda}$$